# Copying to table error, 0xc0202009, 0xc020901c, 0xc0209029 and 0xc0047022

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, sql-server-2012, ssms

[image]

SQL Server Management Studio 2012 is showing up this error when I try to import excel data to an existing table. I'm not sure what is the error here and I do not know how to fix it...

Can you tell me what is the error here?

Comment: Any foreign keys defined in `Staff`?

Comment: Yes, 1 foreign key @JoachimIsaksson

Comment: My first guess would be that one or more of the rows in excel contain a value for the foreign key that does not exist in the referenced table.

Comment: I see, is there any workaround or solutions to this? I am very new to SQL. @JoachimIsaksson

Comment: I presume the foreign key is there for a reason, so hard to give a generic solution that won't potentially cause data corruption. The only thing that can obviously be done is to import the data into a temp table without the foreign key and try to figure out which references are wrong and why.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I've undid all the foreign keys and added the data into a temp table. I'm trying to figure out where I'm doing wrong. Here is the comparison of the temp table and Position table. http://imgur.com/gEbfebm

The data is a fake. I'm practicing this for experience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106832/discussion-between-kuyo-and-joachim-isaksson).